# Does G.655 fiber supports 1310 nm wavelength?

Tags: fiber, sfp

I am using G.655 standard fiber for a project. We are using short haul SFP & long Haul SFP. Long haul (1550 nm) works fine with G.655 fiber, But Short haul SFP (1310 nm) is having some issue as link is not getting up. I am not sure whether the issue is coming because use of short haul at 1310nm.

Is 1310nm wavelength supported in G.655 fiber with cable cut off wavelength?

Comment: Duplicate of http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22235/does-g-655-fiber-supports-1310-nm-wavelenght

Answer (score 1):

G.655 fibers were mainly used to support long-haul systems that use DWDM transmission. It has a small, controlled amount of chromatic dispersion in the C-band (1530-1560 nm), where amplifiers work best. Short haul SFP (1310 nm) will work best over G.652 fiber. Visit http://www.fs.com/blog/what-kind-of-single-mode-fiber-should-you-choose.html for more guide.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, G.655 fibers were mainly used to support long-haul systems that use DWDM transmission. So short haul SFP (1310 nm) doesn't work with G.655 fiber.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with the above two people, single-mode fiber are available in in ITU-T G.652, 653, 654, 655, 656 or 657 standard. Of which G.655 fiber is designed to be used in long-haul application, thus the short reach SFP (1310 nm) will not be compatible.